# React: Re-render strange behavior

Tags: reactjs

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-lumiere-srnyu?file=/src/App.js

I found the console is print 3 times and the last time was `state:2,version:1`, but the view is keep `state:2,version:0`.

I can't understand what happen in React.

#### **I thought that "React would not call re-render if set the same value (primitive value)"**, But this example overthrew my idea.

The initial value of `v` is `true` (line 12), it will call third re-render if call `setV(true)`(line 16), But not update on the View in this re-render call.

Just call 1 times if comment lines 8 to 10.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

let version = 0;

export default () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   setState(2);
  // }, []);

  const [v, setV] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      version = 1;
      setV(true);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  console.log(`state:${state},version:${version}`);

  return (
    <div>
      {`state:${state},version:${version}`}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: React has correctly determined that `v` is not rendered to the screen, so calling `setV()` doesn't need a re-render. You've "shadowed" `version`

Comment: @millhouse thanks your comment, actually you can found the render function called in console after 1s, just not update the View.

Answer (score 0):

`version` is not part of the state, the state being what React uses to decide if it needs to re-render a component.

Comment: I think you are right, but i can't understand why call the third re-render if set the same value to `v`.

Comment: @user6047806 your component function ran a third time but did not render a third time. That is why `version` is still 0. React doesn't "call rerender", it reruns your function component and decides what updates if any to render to the screen based on its diffing algorithm. React did not apply any DOM updates (as expected) when calling `setV` with the same value already held in state. https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: I was trying to inspect what's happening, but myself caught in another doubt. https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-field-fiu6p?file=/src/App.js

Here is the code. Here why am I getting **skipped render count**, i.e. from 2 to directly 4 instead of 3. and when `button click function` set states to `true`, it does not show and console.log but when `button click function` set states to `false`, state changes to false, but when it is again clicked for `false`, why it again rerenders? Pls explain this also